# WP MashShare Plugin breaks my site when enabled

Tags: php, wordpress

When I activate the Mashshare plugin, it gives me the following error when browsing the website like below:

```
Fatal error: Class ‘WPChromePHP’ not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\mashsharer\includes\debug\classes\MashDebug.class.php on line 238
```

I’m using the Mashshare plugin on my website running on WordPress 4.7.5, PHP 5.6, hosted in Azure Webapps.

Anyone have faced it before or knows how to fix?

Comment: It seems to be an issue coming from upstream. [As you already reported it](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mashshare-plugin-breaks-my-site-when-enabled/), did you tried to use an older version? Did you tried to look for a class called `WPChromePHP` in plugin's tree?

Comment: This might be relevant: [WPChromePHP.class.php](https://github.com/mashshare/MashShare/blob/master/includes/debug/browsers/WPChromePHP.class.php)